# Is it possible to run a unix command from inside a YAML file?

Tags: unix, amazon-web-services, sed, yaml, app.yaml

I am writing a YAML file following [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref-example.html) structure.

My exact code is this:

```
# This is an appspec.yml template file for use with AWS CodeDeploy.
# The lines in this template starting with the hashtag symbol are 
#   instructional comments and can be safely left in the file or 
#   ignored.
# For help completing this file, see the "AppSpec File Reference" in the  
#   "AWS CodeDeploy User Guide" at
#   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/app-spec-ref.html
version: 0.0
# Specify "os: linux" if this revision targets Amazon Linux, 
#   Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL), or Ubuntu Server  
#   instances.
# Specify "os: windows" if this revision targets Windows Server instances.
# (You cannot specify both "os: linux" and "os: windows".)
os: linux 

hooks:
  AfterInstall:
   - location: StartUIServices.sh
     timeout: 180
     runas: root
```

The problem is I need run a Unix command that is either `cd` to a another directory or `sed -i 's/\r$//' file1*`(converting a file to Unix line ending) before the location script is ran. How can I do so?

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not you cannot run a command from inside a YAML file depends. There is no provision in the YAML specification to do so.
Of course a YAML parser could still implement this functionality, or, more likely, a program can interpret the data from the YAML parser and execute commands based on its contents. If the program is unsafe it might allow tagged YAML to be loaded and in that case the only restrictions on what instances of object are created would lie within the implementation language of the parser or the program.

If AWS would do such unsafe loading, which is a huge security risk, we would have heard about someone doing an exploit of this.

The AWS instance does a safe load of the YAML data and interprets the loaded data. It has built in provisions to Run scripts before installation ( with the `BeforeInstall` hook) . The first of those scripts should do the DOS to UNIX line end conversion, on all the other scripts, but of course cannot do so on itself. And as you probably noticed scripts with DOS line endings don't run well. You'll have to do the conversion of the first script by other means and not further change it. It should be just a simple script that converts the others that are run later by the same or other hooks, so that you can  provide those other, changing, scripts, from a Windows host.